# where clauses in max statement

Tags: sql

how it is possible to add where to query , to do converting or replacing or max value!

```
max(convert(int,replace(( QueueNum ),'-',''))) from [Queue]
```

i want to return max of records that have something special , in where clauses for QueueNum .

**Edited :**

Data :

```
1981-1-1232
1981-1-1235
1981-1-1234
1981-2-1
1981-2-2
1981-2-13
```

how it is possible to return max value of just record started with  `1981-2`

Comment: can you explain a little bit further?

Comment: what is your desired result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess it is MSSql database in this case try to use the following statement without any conversion:

[SQLfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/81e39/2)

```
select TOP 1 
QueueNum
from Queue where QueueNum like '1981-2-%'
order by LEN(QueueNum) desc, QueueNum desc
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I am giving a good answer, but you can write your query as

```
Select max(MyValue) from (Select Convert(int, replace((QueueNum),'-','')) as MyValue from [Queue]) MyTable
```

What it does is that it create a Temporary table in memory which is of one column MyValue and of type Int, this then find Max from that table. I notice that sometime "MyTable" [table alias] is important in such query to perform especially on SQl Server.

Answer (score 0):

Put your condition in **having** clause

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
SELECT MAX(CONVERT(INT, REPLACE((QueueNum),'-','')))
FROM Queue
WHERE QueueNum LIKE '1981-2%'
```

[SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9e771/1).